# Correct way to write an activation spec in Open Liberty for Apache Qpid for Azure Service Bus

Tags: jakarta-ee, azureservicebus, message-driven-bean, qpid, open-liberty

I have successfully configured Apache Qpid JMS client (0.41.0) in Open Liberty to send messages to an Azure Service Bus queue.

My server.xml looks like this:

```
<jndiObjectFactory id="servicebusfactory" libraryRef="qpidlibsid"
   className="org.apache.qpid.jms.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory" 
   objectClassName="org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory">
</jndiObjectFactory>

<jndiReferenceEntry id="qpidconnectionfactory" 
  jndiName="jms/ServiceBus" 
  factoryRef="servicebusfactory">
  <properties remoteURI="amqps://xxx.servicebus.windows.net?amqp.idleTimeout=120000&amp;amqp.traceFrames=true&;jms.username=xxxx&amp;jms.password=xxx"/>
</jndiReferenceEntry>

<jndiObjectFactory id="queuefactory" libraryRef="qpidlibsid"
  className="org.apache.qpid.jms.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory" 
  objectClassName="org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsQueue">
</jndiObjectFactory>

<jndiReferenceEntry id="myqueue" 
  jndiName="jms/myqueue" 
  factoryRef="queuefactory">
   <properties address="myqueue" />
</jndiReferenceEntry>
```

Using the above server config I can send messages without issues to a Service Bus queue (using a JMS message producer).

The problem is receiving messages using a message-driven-bean. I have tried this config:

```
@MessageDriven(name = "processorMDB", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "jms/myqueue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "connectionFactoryLookup", propertyValue = "jms/ServiceBus"),
})
```

I get a warning when starting Open Liberty:

> [WARNING ] CNTR4016W: The message endpoint for the processorMDB message-driven bean cannot be activated because the jms/myqueue destination is not available. The message endpoint will not receive messages until the destination becomes available.

I need some kind of activation spec I assume, but I cannot get it to work correctly.

Help or explanation on how to use the activation spec in Open Liberty is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you need to [configure a JMS activation spec](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_jms_config_actspec.html).  To do that you need to install a JMS resource adapter, which requires the jms-2.0 feature,

```
 <featureManager>
  <feature>jms-2.0</feature>
  <feature>mdb-3.2</feature>
  ... other features
 </featureManager>

 <resourceAdapter id="myJMSResourceAdapter" location="C:/adapters/jmsRA.rar"/>

 <jmsActivationSpec id="processorMDB">
   <properties.myJMSResourceAdapter .../>
 </jmsActivationSpec>

 <jmsQueue jndiName="jms/myqueue">
   <properties.myJMSResourceAdapter .../>  
 </jmsQueue>
```

Comment: Where can I find a a suitable resource adaptor? I thought Apache Qpid provided what was needed and "acted" as a resource adaptor. Also, doesn't  Open Liberty provide the necessary implementation for this? I am a bit confused about the moving parts here :-)

Comment: This looks like the link to their resource adapter in Maven,
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.qpid/qpid-ra

Answer (score 0):

I never got the MDB to work.

I used a normal MessageListener on the JMSConsumer and it works nicely even though the Javadoc states the following:

> This method must not be used in a Java EE web or EJB application. Doing so may cause a JMSRuntimeException to be thrown though this is not guaranteed.

Code is:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class CreditProcessorBeanListener {

@Resource(name = "jms/ServiceBus")
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

@Resource(name = "jms/myqueue")
private Queue myqueue;
private JMSContext context;
private JMSConsumer consumer;


@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    initListener();
}

private void initListener() {
    context = connectionFactory.createContext();
    consumer = context.createConsumer(myqueue);
    consumer.setMessageListener(new MyListener());

}

@PreDestroy
private void destroy() {
    consumer.close();
    context.close();
}
}
```

Why is MessageListener use on the JMSConsumer not "allowed" in JavaEE? Any comments on that?